# The correspondence theorem w.r.t the determinant ( the abelianization, in general )

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ and $H$ be non abelian and abelian group, respectively. let $f$ be an abelianization $f : G \to H$ such that $G/K$ is isomorphic to $\text{Im}(f)$ where $K$ is $\ker(f)$.

By the correspondence that state that there is a set theoretic bijection beween all subgroups of $\text{Im}(f)$ and all subgroups of of $G$ containg $K$ the kernel of $f$, now in abelianization, if $K \subset L \subset G$ then every conjugate subgroup of $L$, $gL{g^{-1}}$ have same homomorphic image under the abelianization f, namely, $\text{Im}(L) = \text{Im}(gL{g^{-1}}) \text{ for } g \in G$, and we know that $K \subset gL{g^{-1}}$, but L is not normal in G, then there is a contradiction in correspondence theorem since correspondence is unique i.e. for every subgroup $J$ of $H$  there is unique subgroup $f^{-1}(J)$ containing $K$, in our case there are two isomorphic subgroups by conjugation containing $K$ and have same image under $f$.

How could this be possible?

Comment: For inline formulas, enclose the formula in `$...$`.  For displayed formulas, use `$$...$$`. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: thanks. can someone please give me an answer to this question. thanks alot.

Comment: You have proved that in this situation $L$ must be normal in $G$. Or equivalently, if $G/K$ is an abelian quotient group of a group $G$, then any subgroup $L$ of $G$ with $K \le L \le G$ is normal in $G$.

Comment: thanks alot Derek Holt. i made a mistake and not realizing that every preimage of a normal subgroup is normal in the domain.